# Specific Cache Hit Rate calculation

Tags: caching, math, probability, random-access

Scenario:

Suppose we have infinite cache memory size. Caching is just limited by timeout, value of this timeout is half an hour. Cache is initially empty.

Problem:

We have `50,000` distinct request. Our system is querying, **randomly**, at the rate of `15` request/second i.e. `27,000` request in half an hour . What kind of curve or average value of cache hit rate could we expect for first `5` hours?

**Note**: This scenario is fixed. I need an approach to find out hit rate. If you think tag is wrong, please suggest appropriate tag.

Comment: I'm guessing you also have a lazy cache initialization policy, i.e. the cache is empty at the start. Given your infinite memory, why not pre-populate all 50k data points? This will trade off a small load time with a 100% hit rate.

Comment: You are correct, but i can only query at that rate and timeout set will not let me take that kind of advantage. It is more of mathematical kind of question.

Comment: would also have to refresh the dataset every half hour, and that's 50k points per half hour vs the organic request rate of 27k / half-hour, no longer quite as small a load time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right and this is a math question (certainly not a programming
problem).

One approach is to consider the extremes -- what is the hit rate for the
first query when the the system starts running?  For the second query?
After one second?  After 10?  After a minute?  And what is the likelyhood
that any random query will be found in the cache once the system has been
running a long time?

These are few specific values, and together they give you a curve.
I don't think great numeric precision is necessary; the long-term average
and the shape of the curve is more interesting.